# centos 7 haproxy.service stop sometimes

Tags: centos, haproxy, cpan

l’m on centos 7 with cpanel & WHM, i have haproxy binded to port 80 thats workings fine, every day at a random time the haproxy stops so i have to start the service again (service enabled). please any help.
in the haproxy log i find :

```
...haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=0
```

and no details why it stopped.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738399/edit) the question and add logsnippets around the stop event (incl. before)? Please don't post them as images, but straight on text, and surround the log with the code brackets `{ }` to preserve formatting. Every time you have something new to add (answer to question, clarification, test result...) it's best to edit the question directly. That way it stays up-to-date with your situation and all the relevant info is readily available.

Comment: Peregrino was talking about the icon `{}` on the UL SE web interface when editing, not asking to actually type brackets. And also, logs are needed. Something that will tell why it stopped, not just that it stopped, because if you don't provide more logs, nobody will be able to help.

Comment: Also normally this question should have been asked on SF, but with cpanel and WHM it's automatically off-topic there. Too bad.